# gfsh command is not accepting password with special character '!' from gfsh console

Tags: shell, scripting, gemfire, gfsh

Not able to connect to auth enabled gemfire cluster using gfsh console when we have password with special character. Using the below command for login into gemfire cluster

```
gfsh -e "connect --locator=localhost[13120]  --user=$(getProperty 'AUTH_USER') --password=$(getProperty 'AUTH_PASSWORD')"
```

Where the password is something like **'P*Q8!j6c'**. I tried escaping '!' with '\!'. But didn't work.When I manually open gfsh console and provide it manually instead from shell script, it's working fine for me.

It would be a great help if you can help me in passing the password parameter.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me under bash. Try running your gfsh with shell debugging: bash -x gfsh ... then see what it prints as the very last line. This will show how your command args have been expanded. For example mine shows: ` + /Library/.../bin/java -Dgfsh=true -Dlog4j.configurationFile=classpath:log4j2-cli.xml -classpath '<snip...>/lib/gfsh-dependencies.jar:/Users/jdeppe/workspace/gemfire-develop/open/geode-assembly/build/install/apache-geode/extensions/*' org.apache.geode.management.internal.cli.Launcher -e 'connect --user=foo*! --password=foo*!' `

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
eval '$GFSH -e "connect --user=foo --password=S*A8!j6c"'
```

Which avoids the shell trying to expand history. If you're in bash you can also disable history expansion with `set +H`.